# How to find automorphism of a particular order.

Tags: abstract-algebra

Given a finite  group  if  the  automorphism group  is  known  is  it  possible  to  write  down  all  the  automorphisms  with  respective  orders?
For  example say the  group $Z_{p^{2}}$  has  automorphism  group isomorphic  to  $Z_{p(p-1)}$ and I  have  to  find  an automorphism  of  order $p$, $p-1$. Now I know  that one automorphism  of  order $p$  is $y \mapsto y^{p+1}$ . But  how  to  actually find  them  out  for  this  other  groups?

Comment: Can you generalize the automorphism of $\mathbb{Z}/p$ of order $p-1$?

Comment: $Aut(Z_{p})$ is a  cyclic  group of  order  $p-1$ . So  there  are $\phi(p-1)$ such automorphisms . That much I can see but  genaralization?

Comment: Now, what is $p\mathbb{Z}/p^2$ isomorphic to?

Comment: $pZ_{p}$  as  the  elements  are { $p,2p,3p,......(p-1)p$} ?

Comment: And $0$.  (So, how many elements are there?)

Comment: There are $p$ elements.

Comment: But what  next? @MichaelBurr A  little more  help  to  lead  to  the  answer, please?

Answer (score 2):

Below is some background on the automorphism group of any cyclic group $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$, then we give a general way to find such an element of order $p$, and leave the case of powers $p-1$ for the time being.

First, note that an automorphism $\psi:\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}\rightarrow \mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ is completely determined by the image of $1$. So $\psi(1)$ must be an element relatively prime to $n$, otherwise the order collapses. That is, if $\psi(1)=d$ where $\gcd(d,n)>1$, then $ord(d)<n$.

So $\psi(1)$ is relatively prime to $n$ and there are exactly $\phi(n)$ choices for the image of $1$, each of which determine a unique automorphism of the group $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$. This gives $|Aut(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})|=\phi(n)$ and every element of the group is a map $1\mapsto r$ where $\gcd(r,n)=1$.

Let $\psi_r$ denote the map $1\mapsto r$ in $Aut(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})$. To calculate $ord(\psi_r)$ note $\psi_r(1)=r$, $\psi_r(\psi_r(1))=r^2$, and so forth. In this way we can define an isomorphism $Aut(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})\rightarrow (\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})^\times$ by sending $\psi_r\mapsto r$.

So the problem at hand is equivalent to finding the least power $m$ such that $r^m\equiv 1 \pmod{n}$ and to find an element $r$ such that $r^m\equiv 1\pmod{n}$ with $m$ fixed.

Let's work in $\mathbb{Z}/p^2\mathbb{Z}$ for odd primes $p$ now so that the elements of $Aut(\mathbb{Z}/p^2\mathbb{Z})$ are $\{1,...,p-1,p+1,...,2p-1,2p+1,...,p^2-1\}$. We want to choose an element $r$ of the above such that when raised to the power of $p$ we get $1$.

Pick a general element $(mp+k)$ where $k\in \{1,...,p-1\}$ and $m\in \{0,...p-1\}$. By the binomial theorem we have

$$(mp+k)^p=\sum_{i=0}^p {p\choose i}(mp)^{p-i}(k)^i$$

Taking congruences modulo $p^2$ gives the last two terms

$$(mp+k)^p\equiv {p\choose p-1}(mp)k^{p-1}+k^p\equiv k^p \pmod{p^2}$$

Where the last congruence is found after calculating ${p\choose p-1}=p$. So we can check all powers $k^p\equiv 1 \pmod{p^2}$ where $k\in \{1,...,p-1\}$ and we get all others by varying $m\in \{0,...,p-1\}$.

To find at least one solution observe $k=1$ satisfies $k^p\equiv 1 \pmod{p^2}$ so that we can take any element of the set $\{1, p+1, 2p+1,..., p^2-p+1\}$.

Now for the case to the power of $p-1$ we can follow the above so that the binomial theorem gives

$$(mp+k)^{p-1}=\sum_{i=0}^{p-1}{p-1\choose i} (mp)^{p-1-i}k^i$$

Taking congruences again

$$(mp+k)^{p-1}\equiv {p-1\choose p-2}(mp)k^{p-2}+k^{p-1}=(p-1)(mp)k^{p-2}+k^{p-1}\equiv k^{p-1}-mpk^{p-2}\pmod{p^2}$$

So we want to simplify $k^{p-1}-mpk^{p-2}=(k-pm)k^{p-2}\equiv 1\pmod{p^2}$. I'm currently stuck so I'll think about this last one for a little bit.

Comment: I'm pretty sure in general it is difficult to find elements of particular orders unless you know the group structure itself and have orders in mind. It's possible to just manually check the orders of elements of $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}^\times$ by hand but it's not necessarily easy to find elements of particular orders.

Comment: [Here's a wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_of_unity_modulo_n#Finding_a_primitive_k-th_root_of_unity_modulo_n) that may be relevant to your question.

Comment: I know  that's  not  easy .Actually  I am learning  semi direct products  of  groups  and  automorphisms  are  necessary  for  that , of course  the structures  of  the  groups  being  specified. Examples  are  shown  in  books but I cannot  understand  how  they  found  that  automorphism or  on  what  basis  that  particular  one  is  chosen.

Comment: @user118494 That sounds interesting. I would venture "inspired guess" but it's probably just the use of a lot deeper theory. I don't think I know enough group theory to properly respond. :D